# hideshowvis text shown in Org mode source code

Tags: org-mode, html, hideshow

I am using in Org-mode to document inherited Java code.
Here is shown an enum:

[image]

However, when I export to HTML, the document is rendered like this:
[image]

Which incorrectly shows a `*hideshowvis*` text.
I suspect something might be working wrong between **hideshow** minor mode and Org-mode.

Anyone has deal with this issue?
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled upon this. It depends where/how you enable the `hideshowvis-minor-mode`. In my case I had something like

```lisp
(use-package hideshowvis
  ;; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hideshowvis.el
  :load-path "elisp/"
  :hook (prog-mode . hideshowvis-minor-mode))
```

So, to export correctly I just "disable" the `prog-mode-hook` and export like this

```lisp
(let ((prog-mode-hook nil))
  (org-html-export-to-html))
```

You can easily define a function to call

```lisp
(defun my-export-to-html ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((prog-mode-hook nil))
    (org-html-export-to-html)))
```